# Is this reliable to using Redis Pub/Sub for message-queue compare to RabbitMQ

Tags: redis, message-queue

Is this reliable to using Redis Pub/Sub for message-queue compare to RabbitMQ ?
Because configure and maintain a RabbitMQ message-queue system seems more complicated than Redis.

Answer (score 2):

Redis pub/sub is not meant to be reliable. It does not even queue the messages. Any crash of a subscriber will result in message losses.

There are ways to implement a more secure distributed mechanism with Redis, but it is not with pub/sub.

Comment: A more secure distributed mechanism with Redis,Do you mean RQ (Redis Queue)?

Comment: RQ, Celery, Resque, RPqueue, etc ... anything based on Redis list will be better than pub/sub in term of reliability. Now, if you ask me, RabbitMQ is still ahead of any Redis based queuing solutions when it comes to reliability and high-availability.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help,I think RabbitMQ is still the first choice.